# What is importance of using GPL lincense in linux device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What is the exactly benefit of using MODULE_LICENSE("GPL") in linux device driver development.
i mean what will we lack or gain by not using or using it.
which kernel symbols we will not able to use when we will define MODULE as non GPL.

Comment: In short, there is no difference on what you lack or gain. If you compile a non-gpl library driver into the kernel, the kernel becomes "tainted". What does tainted mean? All it means is the kernel is no longer in a state that can be supported/maintained by the community. See: [**Linux: What is a tainted kernel?**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel) For example if you have the nVidia driver loaded -- well obviously that is something the community cannot maintain, so if you have weird problems, there is no guarantee they can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: @EJP: I disagree with the closing. If the question were about the legal consequences of licensing the code as GPL, then sure, it would not be about programming. But the OP is asking what are the practical consequences of adding the line `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` in your source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big difference is the symbols that are exposed to your module when it is GPL licensed.  If you do not have `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` then symbols that are exported via `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()` will not be visible to your module.  This is basically how Linux enforces what work is considered derivative work of Linux and therefore must be licensed under GPL, although the subject of proprietary modules is always a touchy one and I'm not saying if you don't use any GPL exported symbols your code is not a derivative work of Linux.  Furthermore, if your module is not GPL licensed via the macro, your kernel will be considered [tainted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel).